# How can I make a script that always executes first to execute last?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have two scripts, one of which always executes first because of the asynchronous programming.

I need to make the script that executes first to execute after the other.

I'm programming in Google Apps Script

***Script that always executes first***

```js
<script src="https://p.trellocdn.com/embed.min.js" defer></script>
```

***Script that I want to execute first***

```js
  <script>
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myname => {
     var elem = document.getElementById('myLink');
     elem.href = myname;
     }).getCardById();
  </script>
```

***Function getCardById()***

```js
function getCardById(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSp = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = activeSp.getActiveSheet();
  var linkCol = activeSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  //Logger.log(' LINKCOL:' + linkCol);
  return linkCol;
}
```

Comment: cant you change the order of the tags?

Comment: @ariel sorry they don't change the order who knows why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Change the order of script loading where *both* scripts perform *asynchronous* tasks.

**Solution**

How about doing some good old (well, sort of) dynamic content loading? Consider this: you want to call the backend `getCardById()` function as soon as the content loads, *then* load the Trello library and *then* do something with it. Thus, you need to:

1. Do the async stuff with `getCardById()`
2. Load the library inside `withSuccessHandler()`
3. Attach a `load` listener to ensure the library is loaded
4. Do the preparation inside the `load` handler
5. Then do other stuff

Since judging from your code your goal is likely to embed Trello cards with links pulled from a Spreadsheet, there is a helper function `window.TrelloCards.load()` that redoes the lookup of cards as needed.

**Sample**

```
<blockquote class="trello-card">
  <a id="card">Trello Card</a>
</blockquote>

<script>

  (() => {

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {

      const tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://p.trellocdn.com/embed.min.js";

      tag.addEventListener('load', () => {

        //can start doing something cool...

        const elem = document.querySelector('#card');

        elem.href = 'your card url';

        window.TrelloCards.load(document); // <-- this triggers the lookup
      });

      document.body.append(tag);

    }).doSomethingServerSide();

  })();
```

**Reference**

1. [On demand embedding](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/embedding/embedding-cards/) on Atlassian

Comment: Your example looks very good, i would like to you to explain me more about how it works, so i can introduce it in my own code

Comment: Hi @Rinzler - could you please be more specific about what you don't understand about the solution? As an overview, it takes advantage of the fact that you can dynamically inject external scripts + listen to an event fired when the script finishes loading + call the library (when loaded, it assigns namespaces such as `TrelloCards` to global object, in our case - `window`)

Comment: So first where i should call my function `getCardById()` , there are to many things i never saw before, i'm very new with this. Also the variable `myname` that is the one that should have the link where should i put it?

Comment: Your code worked! , what does the `addEventListener`?

Comment: First thing you need to know is that GAS is basically JavaScript with a few twists, so it would be highly beneficial to start learning it. Your `myname` var prob. contains card url, right? Assign it to `href` attr insode the listener to `load` event. Your call to backend `getCardById()` can stay the same, I just wrapped it into an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: Glad you managed to implement) As for your second question, `addEventListener` is a modern way to assign, well, "listeners" to different events (like click on a button, net state change, etc - the list is huge)

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem.  Here's what defer means: 
`The defer attribute tells the browser that it should go on working with the page, and load the script “in background”, then run the script when it loads. Scripts with defer never block the page. Scripts with defer always execute when the DOM is ready, but before DOMContentLoaded event.`

So this script is going to run just after the DOM loads but before the window.onload event occurs.  And script below requires the DOM to already have been loaded before it can run so you need to put it into a window.onload...

```
<script>
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myname => {
     var elem = document.getElementById('myLink');
     elem.href = myname;
     }).getCardById();
</script>
```

So I don't think you are going to get you wish.  But it's possible that someone who knows Javascript better than I may swoop in and save the day.