# Shopify App Bridge and Google Apps Scripts - not possible?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-app-bridge

I'm trying to build a Shopify embedded app using Google Apps Scripts and am having trouble getting the library to provide any kind of response. I have built an app with App Bridge before using regular JS / HTML / CSS, but I am wondering if there is something that is preventing it from working with Apps Scripts creating the HTML output.

```
function doGet(e) {
// I was experimenting with this and it throws a 'window not defined' error
//  eval(UrlFetch('https://unpkg.com/@shopify/app-bridge@1.25.0/umd/index.js').getContentText());

  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);  
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

And in my Page.html I am including Javascript.html like:

```
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

In Javascript.html I try to initialize the app but the App Bridge library doesn't respond at all in the console. I've also tried to render a ResourcePicker, for example, and nothing happens.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@shopify/app-bridge@1.17.0/umd/index.js"></script>

<script>
      var AppBridge = window['app-bridge'];
      var actions = AppBridge.actions;
      var createApp = AppBridge.default;
      var app = createApp({
        apiKey: {my api key},
        shopOrigin: {shopOrigin}
              });
...
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `And in my Page.html I am including Javascript.html where I import the CDN like this:`? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between the Web Apps by `doGet` and `Javascript.html`.

Comment: I have edited my post to include that relationship

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. In your situation, when those files are used as one HTML file including the HTML and Javascript, what result will you get? Because at first, I would like to confirm whether your issue is due to Web Apps.

Comment: How about [some DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021353/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-always-executes-first-to-execute-last/61022784#61022784) to mitigate (or DCL, if you prefer)? In short, you need to wait until the content is actually loaded before initializing your components

Comment: Thank you. I've tried putting all of the Javascript directly into Page.html and it also does not work or provide any response from App Bridge in console.

Comment: @OlegValter thank you, I took your code and placed it in my JavaScript.html file. I replaced the .doSomethingServerSide() with a random function I've defined, changed the tag.src to the App Bridge library, and in the do something cool portion I've tried to initialize app bridge there. 

Now in console it's showing me Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY (and back again) which is what I'm familiar with seeing when App Bridge is starting - but nothing after that. Am I supposed to do something with window.TrelloCards.load(document)? I deleted that, but is there an equivalent for my case?

Comment: @policenauts - well, I did not say literally :) You can listen to a "load" event without running a smth on the server (the question asked for loading a library after the server-side actions complete). I am not well-versed in Shopify, so I can't say for sure, afaik calling `createApp` instantiates it and you need to call action-specific methods to do something. Should it do something else? re:idle/busy - FYI, they are logs of request firing to GAS server-side with `google.script.run` (busy) and closing (idle), responding with data if any (not sure what you mean by familiar with App Bridge)

Comment: Oh, and one more thing - please avoid "eval(UrlFetch('https://unpkg.com/@shopify/app-bridge@1.25.0/umd/index.js')". That is as dangerous as it gets. If you need to use the library, paste in the source code (or the minified version) into a separate file or use a GAS-specific version of the lib if it has one (many popular ones do have either official or enthusiast-created)